# Does VS Community 2019 support Xamarin Forms Shell UWP?

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.shell

When I started my solution in VS Community 2019 it said that the Xamarin Forms Shell did not support UWP. I just upgraded VS to 16.9.2 and it now says UWP is a "Preview feature."

So I have a partially-completed Solution with Android and iOS projects. How do I add a UWP project to the existing mostly-completed solution? I try Solution->Add->Project and it seems to want to start a whole new app.

Comment: you can either add a "plain" UWP app to your existing solution and then manually add the XF nugets and setup the project references, or you could try creating a new XF solution that includes all three projects types, and then manually add just the UWP project to your existing solution.  Either way requires a bit of work on your part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does VS Community 2019 support Xamarin Forms Shell UWP?

Currently, Visual Studio has not provide complete project template for Xamarin Forms Shell
for UWP platform, and derive from [Xamarin Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/introduction#platform-support) document.

> Xamarin.Forms Shell is fully available on iOS and Android, but only partially available on the Universal Windows Platform (UWP). In addition, Shell is currently experimental on UWP

As @Jason said, If you do want to add UWP support, please add the project manually, and [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/UserInterface/Xaminals) is official code sample that contains UWP client. you could refer this to add UWP client.

```
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("Shell_UWP_Experimental");
```

For add UWP project for xamarin forms please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/windows/installation/).

Comment: Thanks @Nico Zhu. I am going to mark this accepted. Obviously I have not made the changes yet but I will.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it kind of working. Some issues, but it loads and runs. I created a vanilla app from the new solution template, and used that as a model to hack on the project that was created in my solution from New, Project, UWP.